# How to remove an item from an array before running next method?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a card shuffling program that returns a random card from an array, then deletes that array item so it can't be dealt again. Then, the program repeats. I've been working on this for quite a while and nothing seems to be working. I think the issue is that the program isn't accessing the updating array/the program isn't executing in a linear order, but I'm not sure.

```
var shuffler = {
  cards: [...],
  displayCard1: function() {
   document.getElementById("card-1").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + 
this.cards[this.randomizer()] + ')';
  },
  displayCard2: function() {
    document.getElementById("card-2").style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + 
this.cards[this.randomizer()] + ')';
  },
   ...
  },
  randomizer: function() {
    var randomized = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length);
    this.cards.splice(this.randomized, 1);
    return randomized;  
  }
};
shuffler.displayCard1();
shuffler.displayCard2();
...
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me :

```
 randomizer: function() {
    // take shuffle from your array 
    var randomized = this.cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length)];

    // Get Index of element to be removed 
    const index=this.cards.indexOf(randomized);
    // remove element at this index
    this.cards.splice(index, 1);  
  }
```

Now you can directly call

```
this.randomizer();
```

Comment: randomizer: function() {
        let randomizedCard =  this.cards[Math.floor(Math.random() * 
    this.cards.length)];
        const index = this.cards.indexOf(randomizedCard);
    this.cards.splice(index, 1);
        return randomizedCard;
     }

Like this?

Answer (score 0):

You remove the element from the array and then try to display that element:

```
this.cards[this.randomizer()]
```

where radomizer has already removed the card you are trying to access.  You will now be accessing the next card in the array instead, or possibly off the end of the array.

Answer (score 0):

```
let removedCard = this.cards.splice(this.randomizer(), 1)
```

Except change your `randomizer()` function to not splice the card, just return a random index.

```
randomizer: function() {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * this.cards.length);
}
```